# ASP.NET Core user authentication based on certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, x509certificate

I'm building a small ASP.NET Core application. One of the requirements is to grant users ability to login by certificate instead of using login/password pair.

**Example of login page**

[image]

**I found several examples, usually they are based on the following approach**

1. User installs CSP (cryptographic service provider) plugin for the selected web-browser (plugin provides functionality to access user certificate store, sign data, etc directly from the browser via JavaScript API calls)
2. Login form contains hidden input fields with a pre-generated XML document in it.

Xml document example

```
<loginrequest>
  <currentTimestamp>123456789012345678</currentTimestamp>
  <requestGuid>ba3d3b37-319f-4551-8c15-1abe4dce854e</requestGuid>
</loginrequest>
```

- User selects certificate from the certificates list
- User presses **LOGIN** button (login button has onClick handler which signes Xml document via CSP browser plugin)
- Form is been submitted (form fields consists of - signed xml document data, selected certificate thumbprint, raw xml document)
- On the servers side signed xml document is been validated against thumbprint. If sign is valid, system search the appropriate user in DataBase by matching the thumprint (each user in DataBase has thumbprint column). If user was found servers issues a JWT acccess token at let him in.

**I am interested in the following questions**

- Does this approach have any kind of specification (like Mutual-TLS in
  OAuth 2.0) with detailed information about contents of Xml generate
  document and how to properly validate it?
- It there any other ways to
  authenticate user by certificate in ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Comment: Have you read this? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @RyanWilson yep. It seems that it's not exactly solves my issue since it's just totaly replaces login/password approach as far as I understood from the documentation

Comment: Certificate authentication takes place before any requests come through by the user, so you would either authenticate them immediately via certificate or you would present them a login page for username and password. You wouldn't be doing them at the same time, unless I read the certificate authentication piece completely wrong, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I would think you would just make it easy on the user and try to authenticate via certificate, if that fails, then present the user a login page with username and password fields.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks for detailed explanations! In my case certificate authentication is just an alternative way to log in. User can choose to use a login/password pair or certificate.

Comment: @Anton have you found answer for your question? Solving similar use-case.

Comment: @TomasIvan I end up using custom approach based on steps I had describred erlier.